# Earning through Lyft while receiving California unemployment

Tags: california, unemployment

I've read that some states allow a maximum weekly income while on unemployment. I'm wondering if one is able to earn while on California unemployment, and if so, what the maximum is.

Comment: They said "states", so probably not Canada. Also, the user has other posts about California taxes.